# Changing image src depending on screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the image src depending on the screen size using media queries. I tried background:url(x); but it didn't work. I read somewhere that I should use content:url(x) instead, but when I do so, I get a blank page. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="at-header">
  <img class="image" id="logo" src="img/logo_white.png" />
  <img class="image" id="main-img" src="img/desktop_homepage.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){   
    #main-img{      
        content:url("img/mobile_homepage.jpg");
    } 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {      
    #main-img{      
       content:url("img/tablet_homepage.jpg");
     } 
} 
@media (min-width: 992px){      
      #main-img{        
          content:url("img/desktop_homepage.jpg");  
      } 
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {    
     #main-img{         
         content:url("img/desktop_homepage.jpg");   
     } 
}
```

Comment: Do you have this on a server?

Comment: if that css is in an external file, then remember that urls in css files are relative to the css file, not the html that the css rule applies to.

Comment: Try using the background-image css rule, make sure the address is relative to the css file.

Comment: I just tried switching your image urls to external pages - it works fine, so I think @MarcB is right. https://jsfiddle.net/xshaz32e/

Comment: Yep, it was a url problem. I was writing it relative to my html file. Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

this is working for me:

```css
#main-img {
  
  height: 250px;
  width:100%
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {   
    #main-img{
     background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/dark_embroidery.png);
    } 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {      
    #main-img{      
     background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/dark_embroidery.png);
    } 
} 
@media (min-width: 992px) {      
      #main-img{        
          background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/paisley.png);
      } 
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {    
     #main-img{         
         background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/paisley.png);
     } 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
    <div id="main-img" />
</div>
```

Comment: Good for static URLs. But this doesn't solve for URLs created dynamically or received from WebService/Database

Comment: This only works with a height set. Is there a way to make it so the height expands dynamically to match the width of the div, while maintaining the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 87):

This one is working for me. I don't know if you're familiar with this tag but it doesn't even need CSS.

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 900px)" srcset="BigImage.png">
    <source media="(min-width: 480px)" srcset="MediumImage.png">
    <img src="OtherImage.png" alt="IfItDoesntMatchAnyMedia">
</picture>
```

In this case "BigImage" Would show when the device width is more than 900px. "MediumImage" when its's more than 480px and "OtherImage" If It's less than 480px. If you had "max-width: 900px" instead of min-width, it would also show when the width is more than 900px.

Hope it helps!

Comment: where do you find this, I am trying this for select but doesn´t work, or it is just for image?

Comment: I think it works only for images, but maybe other tags could help make it work for other stuff

Comment: This is an incredibly useful technique to save you editing CSS for one off tasks etc.

Comment: Note this is not supported in IE at all https://caniuse.com/#feat=picture

Answer (score 14):

We already have feature to load images based on screen sizes. You don't need CSS Media query for that. because to load dynamic images coming from database it's not feasible for you to create media query on the fly.

SOLUTION :

Use `srcset` attribute

EXAMPLE :

```
<img src="small.jpg" srcset="medium.jpg 1000w, large.jpg 2000w" alt="yah">
```

in the above code all you need to define is width size next to the images separated by commas.

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Note that this currently is [not supported by IE at all](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-html_elements_img_srcset).  It may be best to go with the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30461063/8112776)'s [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/@media) solution in the css, for [compatability](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_at-rules_media).

Comment: IE sucking like always

Comment: @ashleedawg true, but as i clearly mentioned those are for static urls and images which u already have in ur assets. When u have a fixed url then you can use it in media query but wht about those url which u receive from web service/database ? you can't create media query in that case. The only solution without using srcset will be by getting the screen size using javascript and then setting the url based on the condition whether its a Mobile/Tab/Desktop

Answer (score 8):

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
</picture>
```

Let's fix this, with `<picture>`! Like `<video>` and `<audio>`, The `<picture>` element is a wrapper containing several `<source>` elements that provide several different sources for the browser to choose between, followed by the all-important `<img>` element.

Comment: Note that this currently is [not supported by IE at all](https://caniuse.com/#feat=picture).  It may be best to go with the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30461063/8112776)'s [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/@media) solution in the css, for [compatability](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_at-rules_media).

Comment: It's 2021, and sorry if you're working in companies who still need IE support, but 90% of the internet has moved on.

Comment: Note that this is not supported by Netscape 4.X. For compatibility, images should be sent out on floppy disks only.

Answer (score 3):

Try this my friend:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {   
    #main-img{
        content: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/dark_embroidery.png) !important;
    } 
}
```

The !important declaration will solve all your problems.
I promise.

Comment: Rather than promise, make an example that will prove it.