# Change LOCAL Image Source depending on screen size

Tags: html, css

I want to change an image depending on screen size, the image is a good size when in mobile size, but when it is full screen the image is too big. 
I have asked this question inside another question.

It has worked for a URL, but I do not understand how to make it work for a local image. e.g. Img/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43901756/7962671

Thanks,

Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your stylesheet located relative to your img folder? If your site directory is built the following way:

-index.html

-/css

-/img

Then you'll want to change your code to this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {   
 #main-img{
    background-image: url("../img/Well-Being-For-Kids.jpg");
 } 
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {      
 #main-img{      
    background-image: url("../img/Well-Being-For-Kids.jpg");
 }
}
```

Comment: That worked thank you! But now the image is static, I have tried using, position and display, but cannot seem to figure out how to make the image responsive like before. I have tried doing width: 100%, but it does nothing. Any ideas? Thank you for your answer also, I knew it was going to be something ridiculous haha

Comment: What do you mean static? If you're trying to make it be responsive as a background image then you'll want to change your background-image properties. See here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

I have already given answer in another post. visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/54397999/2165382

In case if the post deleted.

We already have feature to load images based on screen sizes. You don't need CSS Media query for that. because to load dynamic images coming from database it's not feasible for you to create media query on the fly.

SOLUTION :

Use `srcset` attribute

EXAMPLE :

```
<img src="small.jpg" srcset="medium.jpg 1000w, large.jpg 2000w" alt="yah">
```

in the above code all you need to define is width size next to the images separated by commas.

Hope it helps :-)