# srcset - show different image based on device

Tags: html, css, srcset

I am tring to show different image based on screen resolution in one <img tag, i read several tutorial but i can't get it work

Screen < 768px show banner_mobile.png (500x500)
More than 768px show banner_desktop.png (1370x200)

```
<img 
    srcset="banner_mobile.png 768w,
            banner_desktop.png 1024w"
    sizes="(max-width: 768px) 768px,
           (max-width: 1024px) 1024px"
    src="banner_desktop.png"
    alt="test">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing image src depending on screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460681/changing-image-src-depending-on-screen-size)

Comment: yes but only if using <picture> is the same performance, I read around that srcset is "faster"

Comment: Look at the non-accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54397999/1172189